# Is there anything wrong with this code where i am using Timer

Tags: android, timer

I am trying to take the recent time and show it in a TextView. And using a Timer and timerTask to get current time every second and update the UI using post method of View object.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
  Button btnStart,btnStop;
  TextView txtRcntTime;
  Calendar c;
  private Timer timer;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initialize(); // method where i initialized all components

     c = Calendar.getInstance();

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStart:
                start();
                break;
        case R.id.buttonStop:
                stop();
                 break;

    }
}

public void stop()
{
     if (timer!=null){
         timer.cancel();
         timer = null;
        }
  }

private void start() 
{
  if(timer != null)
    {  timer.cancel();  }

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm-ss a");
            String formattedDate1 = df1.format(c.getTime());
            updateView(formattedDate1);
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
}

public void updateView(final String t) 
{        
    txtRcntTime.post(new Runnable() {
        String t2 = t;
        @Override
        public void run() 
            {   txtRcntTime.setText(t2);       }
    });
}
}
```

Result is showing the time for the first time when button is clicked but not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

It is actually updating but you are only getting one instance of the calendar thus giving you the same time when the timer task is called every 1 second.

**solution:**

update the calendar by getting the instance of it each second

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm-ss a");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String formattedDate1 = df1.format(cal.getTime());
        updateView(formattedDate1);
    }
};
```

Comment: ohh man!! Thanks alot. sometimes i think that i should leave the programming field :-(